# Cant use Sharekit. "ShareKit must be configured before use"

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, sharekit

If I use the DefaultSHKConfigurator class it tells me it needs to be configured before use.

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'IllegalStateException', reason: 'ShareKit must be configured before use. Use your subclass of DefaultSHKConfigurator, for more info see https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Configuration. Example: ShareKitDemoConfigurator in the demo app'
```

So if I create a custom SHK configurator instead which extends DefaultSHKConfigurator it says that there is a `'Duplicate Interface Definition for class 'DefaultSHKConfigurator''`

In this case Here is the applicationDiDfinishLaunching I am creating the configurator in:

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{
    NSLog(@"application did finish launching.");   
    DefaultSHKConfigurator *configurator = [[CustomSHKConfigurator alloc] init];
    [SHKConfiguration sharedInstanceWithConfigurator:configurator];
}
```

if it is using the DefaultSHKConfigurator the  I cahnge the code to alloc and init a DefaultSHKConfigurator.... However neither methods stop me from getting this error that I dont really understand.

FIX:

It needs to be called in.

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {

Comment: I figured it out.... It needs to be called in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

Comment: `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is depreciated from iOS 3.0 onwards.

Comment: I am confused on how to include the configurator, are we suppose to make a separate .h & .m file and then include this code above in it... or how does it work exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIX: It needs to be called in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
```